# How to extend Firebase App object with new Storage URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

What is the best way to extend the current App instance with the new Storage URL without recreating the object? Creating a completely new App instance resulted in having a user logged in to one (with default bucket) and not to the other one.

It seems that currently one can't save files to several buckets, since `storage()` takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance. Literally you can use other buckets from console UI, but in code you can use only the default bucket. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to extend `FirebaseApp` instance to add a second bucket. But you can specify the bucket for an app instance when you create it, e.g. by calling [`setStorageBucket`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder.html#setStorageBucket(java.lang.String)) or by [specifying your own `storageBucket` value in the config data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).